# What happens if I replace the files of a WordPress site with another WordPress site?

Tags: migration, backup, deployment

I accidentally copied all the files of a WordPress development site (ver 5.1.1) and overwrote another WordPress development site (ver 5.0.4). I did not copy over the database. Each site shares some different plugins and themes. I'm assuming those non-identical files remain.

My question is will my site still work properly? I don't mind if the data is different but will my site still function as usual?

Answer (score 0):

## ‍♂️

It depends on the functionality provided by the plugins and theme.

For example, there could be differences in database schema that some plugins and themes depend on.

Even if the site doesn't break right away, you will probably miss functionality in your site and be left with a bunch of junk data and/or code.

**It's not a good idea to do this. I can't imagine a time where you would want to do this.**

Comment: Could I assume that those themes and plugins would be inactive since there's no database data related to them. Thus, I could activate them and start them from scratch? If so, I guess I'm good to go. Cos I just hate to undo the entire overwriting process and find which codes/files that I changed that need to be replaced.